# Is there any predefined functions for getting previous value in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Simple example:

```
ID     NAME  
-----------   
1      Test  
2      Test1
```

I update `Test1` to `Test3`.

Now result is:

```
ID    NAME  
----------  
1     Test  
2     Test3
```

After updated the field `NAME` I want the  previous value, `Test1`, of the specified field. Is there any predefined function available?

Comment: Once you change the data (and commit the transaction if you use any), the previous values are lost forever. Maybe you can just store the previous value in memory *before* updating the table?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have permanent access to the previous value, an option is to store the it in the database by adding a row 'oldName' to that same table. You could even use a trigger to have the name backed up systematically whenever it is changed:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `backup_name` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
    SET NEW.oldName = OLD.name;
    END IF
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in sql, if you are updating using some other language such as PHP you could store the value then update, that way you still have the old value to hand.  But as someone mentioned ina  comment, once commited the data is lost.

Comment: Well you could do it in SQL too, e.g.: `SET @var=(SELECT name FROM table WHERE ...`).

Comment: @netcoder very true, I had not though of that, however my main point was you need to store the value in a variable before you commit a new value.

Comment: @MariselvamPanneerselvam as netcoder suggested you can do this purely in sql, it depends what you want to do with it after really.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such a function for mysql.

look at transaction for mysql and try to get the value before the `COMMIT` of your transaction

Syntax:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A messy answer would include adding a column called LAST_NAME or alike:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET LAST_NAME=NAME,NAME = 'New Name' WHERE ID = 1
```